# How to resolve setHeader issue in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular8

I have done file uploading process in my application using connect-multiparty.I can upload file and move to local folder.Everything is working perfect except below issue.I do not know why i am getting this error.How to resolve this issue?How to avoid this error.

app.js:

```
  var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
  var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
  var fs = require('fs');

app.post('/api/upload', multipartMiddleware, (req, res) => {
res.json({ 'message': req.files });
var tmp_path = req.files.uploads[0].path;
var target_path = './uploads/' + req.files.uploads[0].name;
fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Upload started")
    fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path);
    });
});
res.end();
});
```

upload.component.ts:

```
upload(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append("uploads[]", this.uploadedFiles[i], this.uploadedFiles[i].name); 
    } 
    this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+'/upload', formData)
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log('response receved is ', response);
    })
  }
```

Error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:526
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\server\app.js:65:17
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 dev: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T17_06_06_701Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `res.json({ 'message': req.files });` is sent always and in case of errors `res.send` is used. This should not be mixed as these sends two different response and content type to client. If your `api` is serving `json`, make sure you alwasy send json and use `res.json` only once.

Comment: Also once you do `fs.rename` of a file, the file will no longer exist in the old name. So performing a `fs.unlink` on the same old name is pointless as it will alwasy throw error!!

Comment: @Panther: So can i remove this line:res.json({ 'message': req.files });

Comment: Nope.. that depends on your logic actually. You need to determine what/when you need to send when the operation is success and failure. Also its good practice to keep all the `res` at the end of the logic or at the place the function exits after sending the response.